# how to build interfaces (wireframes, mockups) for mobile app?

Tags: untagged

Which tools to be used to build mockups for Android mobile app? Can I use Android Studio or is there any other simpler options? I'm not looking to write code I just ant to design interfaces for the app and how the app may function.